# Consistent Mermaid styling between Mermaid Live and GitHub

Tags: github, formatting, mermaid

I'm creating diagrams in Mermaid and I'm new to the framework. I'd like to have consistent formatting between how the diagram is rendered in the [Mermaid Live Editor](https://mermaid.live/) and how the diagram is rendered in Github.

I also render diagrams in Pycharm using the Mermaid plugin, and its styling is currently the same as the live editor.

Here's an example diagram in Mermaid Live/Pycharm:

[image: example diagram in Mermaid Live]

And here's the same diagram as rendered in Github:

[image: example diagram in Github]

The reason I want to do this is because color choices make the diagram look very different in the two editors. When the text color changes from black to white, this can make some text unreadable in one of the two formats (look at the blue box for an example of this).

Comment: I forget what version of mermaidJs GitHub is using, but the difference may come from the use of an older version - or how they are handling the theming options

Can you provide a link to the live editor with your diagram?

Comment: Here's an example: https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNp1kjFPwzAQhf_Kyajq0g4QqBQPTFWmTpQNM7j2pbFwzpHtCKqq_x0naUIp5Ybo8u59PuvJR6acRsZZad2nqqSPsHkRJAhShXa397KpYIN7JD2IXWnjUUXjqDePqrx_e61MgNpYDNERQvopDZlQoX7nnI89LJfPMFEPN6gdGtoDfqFq48AOfVIv9mX_ko2VRAPYt532a-njDZRchAPGCb7Y9HTDLmFOzscKQpR-_jPrlvaDbdKHM_rwxlRnM1hjigIhuDp94iGBw0hZGUIawnTp0ljL7_JURXHlmRI5m4pitcqyK9MU-XhQUfzxTJc9m5TK87IUxBasRl9Lo9P7OHaQYLHCGgXjqdXSfwgm6JR8so1ueyDFePQtLljbaBlxbWR6PzXjpbQBT986ycr7.

I think it's the theming because GitHub using black text compared to the Mermaid editor's white text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

Add `%%{init: {"theme": "dark"}}%%` to your GitHub code block.

### My answer

I assume that your computer is configured to use `dark` theme and not `light`, and that's why you see inconsistency between the two.

For me this is how your [mermaid link](https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNp1kjFPwzAQhf_Kyajq0g4QqBQPTFWmTpQNM7j2pbFwzpHtCKqq_x0naUIp5Ybo8u59PuvJR6acRsZZad2nqqSPsHkRJAhShXa397KpYIN7JD2IXWnjUUXjqDePqrx_e61MgNpYDNERQvopDZlQoX7nnI89LJfPMFEPN6gdGtoDfqFq48AOfVIv9mX_ko2VRAPYt532a-njDZRchAPGCb7Y9HTDLmFOzscKQpR-_jPrlvaDbdKHM_rwxlRnM1hjigIhuDp94iGBw0hZGUIawnTp0ljL7_JURXHlmRI5m4pitcqyK9MU-XhQUfzxTJc9m5TK87IUxBasRl9Lo9P7OHaQYLHCGgXjqdXSfwgm6JR8so1ueyDFePQtLljbaBlxbWR6PzXjpbQBT986ycr7) looks like:

[image: mermaid]

And on GitHub, the markdown:

```
flowchart LR

    subgraph Legend
        direction LR
        a1[This milestone is finished]:::finished -->         a2[This milestone is being executed]:::executing
        a3[This milestone is being planned]:::planning -->         a4[This milestone is not yet planned]
        a5[This milestone is a 'north star' milestone]:::northStar
    end

    %% Define some styles
    classDef planning fill:#9999FF
    classDef executing fill:#FF6633
    classDef finished fill:#99FF33
    classDef northStar fill:#cc99ff
```

Looks like that:

[image: GitHub]

You can explicit specify the theme with `%%{init: {"theme": "<mermaid_theme>"}}%%` like this:

````
```mermaid
%%{init: {"theme": "dark"}}%%
flowchart LR

    subgraph Legend
        direction LR
        a1[This milestone is finished]:::finished -->         a2[This milestone is being executed]:::executing
        a3[This milestone is being planned]:::planning -->         a4[This milestone is not yet planned]
        a5[This milestone is a 'north star' milestone]:::northStar
    end

    %% Define some styles
    classDef planning fill:#9999FF
    classDef executing fill:#FF6633
    classDef finished fill:#99FF33
    classDef northStar fill:#cc99ff
```
````

And this will result in the following markdown:

[image: GitHub-dark]